# javascript bitwise vs logical operations give very different results with or without alerts

Tags: javascript, performance, bitwise-operators

With alert in place I get different results than without it, why?

```js
// without alert, time diff is slightly lower (~20ms)
alert("testodd")
testodd();

function normalodd(a) {
    return (a % 2 == 1);
}

function bitwiseodd(a) {
    return (a & 1);
}

function testodd() {

    var time1 = 0;
    var time2 = 0;
    var x = 0;
    var dif1 = 0;
    var dif2 = 0;
    var control1 = 0;
    var control2 = 0;
    dif1 = new Date()
    for (x = 0; x < 100000000; x++)
        if (normalodd(x))
            control1++;
        else
            control2++;
    time1 = new Date() - dif1;

    control1 = 0;
    control2 = 0;

    dif2 = new Date()
    for (x = 0; x < 100000000; x++)
        if (bitwiseodd(x))
            control1++;
        else
            control2++;
    time2 = new Date() - dif2;

    console.log(" odd normal time " + time1)
    console.log(" odd bitwise time " + time2)
    console.log(" odd bitwise time off normal " + time2 / time1)
}
```

Comment: Consider editing your question to include a description of the differences with and without alerts.

Comment: What logic operators are you talking about?

Comment: `a % 2` and `a & 1` are not the same unless you're using unsigned integers (which I think you don't have in `JS`). To visually see what's the difference: try to put `-1` in `a` and see what's the difference.

Comment: I had more examples, the difference in time and my question was: which of the results was correct. But Someone changed my question, removed code etc. I'm new here so..